# How to prove that $\sin \overline{z}, \cos \overline{z}, e^{\overline{z}}$ are not differentiable?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, derivatives

Since $\overline{z}$ is not differentiable in any point, I tought of saying that by the chain rule the derivative would be:

$$\cos \overline{z}(\overline{z})'$$

and so on... But I think that I can only sau that the derivative is $\cos \overline{z}(\overline{z})'$ if $\cos z$ and $\overline{z}$ are differentiable, but I cannot say that a funciton is not differentiable if $\cos z, \overline{z}$ are not differentiable.

So, how do I prove it?

Comment: $\sin \overline{z}$ is anti-holomorphic, so it must be constant if it is also holomorphic, but it is not.

Comment: @HenryW. what's anti-holomorphic? and why is must be constant if it's holomorphic? It's not bounded.

Comment: Anti-holomorphic means derivative w.r.t. $\overline{z}$ exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(z)$ is complex-differentiable at $z_0$ iff $f(z) = f(z_0)+C(z-z_0)+o(|z-z_0|)$ for some $C$.

Let $g(z) =  f(\overline{z})$. If $f(z)$ is complex-differentiable at $z_0$ and $C = f'(z_0) \ne 0$ then $$g(z) =g(z_0)+\overline{C}(\overline{z-z_0})+o(|z-z_0|)$$ and hence $g(z)$ is not complex-differentiable at $\overline{z_0}$